# Multiple Joins Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

i need to make two joins but with many conditionals where, i have this

```
    $matchThese = [ 'suspended' => 0, 'status' => 1, 'approved' => 1 ];

    $matchOther = [ 'status' => 1, 'approved' => 0 ];

    $deals = ListsDeals::where( $matchThese )->where('stock', '>', 0)->orwhere( $matchOther )->whereDate('end_date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))->limit( 4 )->offset( 0 )->orderBy( 'start_date' )->get();

    $deals_lists = DB::table('deals')
                ->join( 'list_has_deals', 'deals.id', '=', 'list_has_deals.deal_id'  )
                ->join( 'lists', 'list_has_deals.list_id', '=', 'lists.id' )
                ->paginate( 10 );
```

I need one unique query with that two vars, select all deals with the 'WHERES' in the first var and later make the joins, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that could do the trick :

```
$query = ListsDeals::where( $matchThese )->where('stock', '>', 0)->orwhere( $matchOther )->whereDate('end_date', '>', date('Y-m-d'))->limit( 4 )->offset( 0 )->orderBy( 'start_date' );

$results = $query->join( 'list_has_deals', 'deals.id', '=', 'list_has_deals.deal_id'  )
            ->join( 'lists', 'list_has_deals.list_id', '=', 'lists.id' )
            ->paginate( 10 );
```

Comment: I add some more code, that give me error

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'suspended' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `deals` inner join `list_has_deals` on `deals`.`id` = `list_has_deals`.`deal_id` inner join `lists` on `list_has_deals`.`list_id` = `lists`.`id` where (`suspended` = 0 and `status` = 1 and `approved` = 1) and `stock` > 0 or (`status` = 1 and `approved` = 0) and date(`end_date`) > 2017-08-14)

Comment: As you make joins in the query, you need to tell Eloquent in which table make the select with the dot syntax : eg ->where('table.suspended', '=', 'something')